# React Redux routing issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have recently experienced some issues with my react router and redux. Basically, I have a redux value set which let's me know if an item is selected. If the item is selected, then it will allow a URL to be used. One thing that I have noticed. If I add a redirect function. It breaks everything

Authentication function:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
// import store from "./store";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Profile from "./Profile";
import AddDomain from "./AddDomain";
import ChoosePackage from "./ChoosePackage";
import DashboardHome from "./DashboardHome";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_7S0QSNizCdsJdm9yYEoRKSul00z4Pl6qK6");
class index extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("DOMAIN NAME" + this.props.domain_name);
  }
  state = {
    domain_name: ""
  };
  static propTypes = {
    domain_name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };
  domainCheck = () => {
    if (this.props.domain_name != "") {
      return <ChoosePackage />;
    } else {
      console.log("running rediect");
      return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Route path="/dashboard/add-domain/choose-package">
          {this.domainCheck()}
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard/add-domain">
          <AddDomain />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard/profile">
          <Profile />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard">
          <DashboardHome />
        </Route>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  domain_name: state.domain.domain_name
});
index.defaultProps = {
  domain_name: ""
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { pure: false })(index);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: what path are you using in your browser and what is happening exactly?

Comment: @Ramesh so basically. /dashboard/add-domain receives the information about the domain. Afterwards, it's supposed to redirect to /dashboard/add-domain/choose-package. However, if I have it set to the way I have it right now. Itll automatically redirect to /dashboard

Comment: try keeping routes inside `Switch` and give `exact ` for the first route

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu can I have nested switches? Because right now I have another router which takes care of the public pages.

Comment: @A.J if you are redirecting to /dashboard then the if statement is failing...inside domainCheck func